# How to MapReduce with Web Logs?

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, mapping, weblog, reducing

I'm new in Hadoop.
I want to analyze Web logs using MapReduce.
I'll use sample web logs
like this.

```
 211.36.215.78 / [08:Jun:2017:18:00:09] / Link1 / URL1
 210.100.139.14 / [08:Jun:2017:20:10:10] / Link1 / URL2
```

How to analyze 'the number of users accessing the time zone',
               'inflow routes'

Comment: what does _number of users accessing the timezone, inflow routes_ mean? Number of IP addresses accessing a single `Link`?

Comment: Umm.. I mean first is Number of IP addresses accessing each hour of the day. Second is Number of IP addresses accessing a single Link! I'm waiting comment...

Comment: If you want to use MapReduce, then what code do you have so far? Also, if you are new to Hadoop, I'll tell you now that there are much better tools for this than straight MapReduce (e.g. Spark)

Comment: @B.Sung you can refer http://ybhavesh.blogspot.in for few POC done in Hadoop